# factory_girl > association with lazy attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, factory-bot

I'm trying to have a factory build an `Offering` object with a child object `Rating` that will receive the `item_id` from it's parent.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :offering do
    item_id nil
    element_id nil
    association :rating, factory: :rating, strategy: :build, :item => item_id
  end
end
```

The Offering is created with

```
offering = FactoryGirl.create :offering, item_id: 21, element_id: 211
```

But when run, it aborts with an error

```
Failure/Error: offering = FactoryGirl.create :offering, item_id: 21, element_id: 211
 ArgumentError:
   Trait not registered: item_id
```

I assume the error occurs because the `item_id` in the association definition is not "lazy" and therefor undefined.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any way to do lazy evaluation for associations (someone please correct me if I'm wrong on this). Your best bet is probably to use a callback. Assuming you have a factory defined for `:rating`, try replacing your

`association :rating, factory: :rating, strategy: :build, :item => item_id`

with

```
after(:create) do |offering, evaluator|
  FactoryGirl.build(:rating, item_id: evaluator.item_id, element_id: evaluator.element_id)  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can lazily define the association:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :offering do
    item_id nil
    element_id nil
    rating { association(:rating, :item => item_id) }
  end
end
```

Comment: @AliQanavatian can you be more specific? What do you not understand about how to make use of this code example?

Comment: maybe a **create:** statement?